# Reading a specific data from a file using iterator, container and vector using c++

Tags: c++

*Please I want to learn how to read a specific part of a file in c++ using iterator,container and vector .*

This is a sample of a specific read without iterator

```
string rId;
string classes;
string rId1;
string classes1;
fstream file("resultInfo.txt");

    cout<<"Registration Id:";
    cin>>rId1;
    cout<<"Class:";
    cin>>classes1;

    std::string theSubject;
    double theResult;
    double sum =0;
    int count = 0;

    cout <<"\n\n PRINTING RESULTS\n\n\n";


while(file>>classes>>rId>>theSubject>>theResult){
        if(rId==rId1){

  if(classes==classes1){
       cout <<theSubject<<" "<<theResult<<endl;
            sum +=theResult;
            count++;
                    }
                    else{
                        cout <<"CLASS NOT FOUND"<<endl;
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
```

And this is an example of the iterator version

```
ifstream 
file("studentInfo.txt");
string content;
cout<<endl<<"\t\t\t\t !** STUDENT LIST **!\t\t\n\n\n";
cout << setw(15) <<"REG.ID:" << setw(15) << "F.NAME" << setw(15) << "L.NAME" <<setw(15) << "CLASS"<<setw(15)<<"M.NUMBER"<< endl<<endl;
string line;
while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    istringstream ss(line);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss), end;

    //putting all the tokens in the vector
    std::vector<std::string> arrayTokens(begin, end);

    vector<string>::iterator it;

    for(it = arrayTokens.begin(); it != arrayTokens.end(); it++)
    {

            cout<<setw(15)<<*it;// prints d.

    }
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

}

But the issue is, this iterator version will print everything in the file, but what I actually want is to use this iterator to print a specific part of the file, like the first code above.

Am sorry for making the question so long, I just want to describe the issue better.

Thanks to you all...

Comment: In the "iterator" version there's really no need for iterators or vectors at all, you can just use `ss>>classes>>rId>>theSubject>>theResult` very much like in the previous version. And then you can compare the values directly like in the first version.

Comment: Ok , thanks will try that